# git-crypt fails to recognize cloned repository

Tags: git-crypt

I have two computers, a desktop and a laptop. I setup `gpg` and `git-crypt` on the desktop, and it seems to be working great. I can encrypt and decrypt individual files with `gpg`, as well as sign git commits on both laptop and desktop. That's working great.

I exported my public and private keys `gpg` keys on the desktop and imported them on the laptop.

But, `git-crypt` seems to only work on the desktop. It transparently encrypts files when pushed to Github, but when I clone the repository on my laptop I can see the encrypted files, but `git-crypt` says they are not encrypted, and refuses to *actually* decrypt them.

Running `git crypt unlock` prompts me for my GPG key, and seems to accept it, but doesn't actually do anything.

I'm not sure what's going on, or how I can make `git-crypt` recognize that it's actually an encrypted repository. Any suggestions?

```
➜  Vimwiki git:(master) git crypt status
not encrypted: .git-crypt/.gitattributes
not encrypted: .git-crypt/keys/default/0/7405D8B8BCCCEA723B3BA6615AEA60852688245D.gpg
not encrypted: .gitattributes
not encrypted: index.md
➜  Vimwiki git:(master) git crypt unlock
➜  Vimwiki git:(master) cat index.md
GITCRYPT_5?hV?b_g$<8??M)?blablabla…  

➜  Vimwiki git:(master)
```

Comment: Having exactly the same problem. Did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: Nope, just wound up not using git-crypt and vimwiki.